# Resize disk in VMware

Tags: partitioning, vmware

Trying to make the disk size larger in Ubuntu 15.04 server running in VMware ESXi 5.5

Steps done:

1. downloaded vm from server to local fusion app running os osx.
2. resized the disk space allocation from 90 gigs to 250 gigs
3. output of fdisk -l:

   Disk /dev/sda: 90 GiB, 96636764160 bytes, 188743680 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x8e594b89

   Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
   /dev/sda2       501758 188741631 188239874 89.8G  5 Extended
   /dev/sda5       501760 188741631 188239872 89.8G 8e Linux LVM

   Disk /dev/mapper/filestore--vg-root: 88.8 GiB, 95302975488 bytes, 186138624 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk /dev/mapper/filestore--vg-swap_1: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
4. output of fdisk /dev/sda:
   Command (m for help): p

   Disk /dev/sda: 90 GiB, 96636764160 bytes, 188743680 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x8e594b89

   Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
   /dev/sda2       501758 188741631 188239874 89.8G  5 Extended
   /dev/sda5       501760 188741631 188239872 89.8G 8e Linux LVM
5. tried to create a logical partition but got the error "No free sectors available"
6. tried to create a primary partition which worked:

   Command (m for help): n
   Partition type
      p   primary (1 primary, 1 extended, 2 free)
      l   logical (numbered from 5)
   Select (default p): p
   Partition number (3,4, default 3): 3
   First sector (499712-188743679, default 499712):
   Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (499712-501757, default 501757):

   Created a new partition 3 of type 'Linux' and of size 1023 KiB.

   Command (m for help): t
   Partition number (1-3,5, default 5): 3
   Hex code (type L to list all codes): 8e

   Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux LVM'.
7. wrote changes. ran partprobe. jumped back into fdisk:

   Command (m for help): p

   Disk /dev/sda: 90 GiB, 96636764160 bytes, 188743680 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x8e594b89

   Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
   /dev/sda2       501758 188741631 188239874 89.8G  5 Extended
   /dev/sda3       499712    501757      2046 1023K 8e Linux LVM
   /dev/sda5       501760 188741631 188239872 89.8G 8e Linux LVM
8. tried to initialize the partition. no luck:

   me:~$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3
     Device /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering).

Stuck here.

Was hoping it worked and then was planning to:

1. vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/sda3
2. lvextend -L+160G /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
3. ext2online /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00

Any help is appreciated.

If needed here are some more details:
-Ubuntu server 15.04
-ESXi 5.5 free version
-RAID on ESXi
-VMWare hardware version 8

spanx!